# 'does not implement interface member 'System.ICloneable.Clone()'

Tags: c#, icloneable

I'm having a small issue calling in the Icloneable interface

I've told the class I want to use the interface as such:

```
class UnitClass: ICloneable
```

and have placed in a function for Cloning

```
    public Object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
```

however for  some reason the program is telling me that I have not implemented System.ICloneable.clone() I even tried giving the function the explicit name like so...

```
 public Object System.ICloneable.Clone()
```

but with little effect, anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

edit: Full class

```
class UnitClass: ICloneable
{

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------Variables----------------------------------------

    private int unitID; //added for xml
    private string unitName;
    private int unitBaseHP;
    private int unitCurrentHP;
    private Carrier unitCarrier;
    private int unitRechargeTime;
    private int turnLastPlayed;
    private int strengthAgainstFighters;
    private int strengthAgainstBombers;
    private int strengthAgainstTurrets;
    private int strengthAgainstCarriers;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------Constructor---------------------------------------

    public UnitClass()
    {
            unitID = 0;
            unitName = "Name Not Set";
            unitBaseHP = 0;
            unitCurrentHP = 0;
            unitCarrier = null;//Carrier works as faction ie red/blue or left/right
            unitRechargeTime = 0;
            turnLastPlayed = 0;
            strengthAgainstFighters = 0;
            strengthAgainstBombers = 0;
            strengthAgainstTurrets = 0;
            strengthAgainstCarriers = 0;
    }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------Gets and Sets-------------------------------------

    public int UnitID//public
    {
        set { unitID = value; }
        get { return unitID; }
    }

    public string UnitName//public
    {
        set { unitName = value; }
        get { return unitName; }
    }

    public int UnitBaseHP//public
    {
        set { unitBaseHP = value; }
        get { return unitBaseHP; }
    }

    public int UnitCurrentHP//public
    {
        set { unitCurrentHP = value; }
        get { return unitCurrentHP; }
    }

    public Carrier UnitCarrier//public
    {
        set { unitCarrier = value; }
        get { return unitCarrier; }
    }

    public int UnitRechargeTime//public
    {
        set { unitRechargeTime = value; }
        get { return unitRechargeTime; }
    }

    public int TurnLastPlayed//public
    {
        set { turnLastPlayed = value; }
        get { return turnLastPlayed; }
    }

    public int StrengthAgainstFighters//public
    {
        set { strengthAgainstFighters = value; }
        get { return strengthAgainstFighters; }
    }

    public int StrengthAgainstBombers//public
    {
        set { strengthAgainstBombers = value; }
        get { return strengthAgainstBombers; }
    }

    public int StrengthAgainstTurrets//public
    {
        set { strengthAgainstTurrets = value; }
        get { return strengthAgainstTurrets; }
    }

    public int StrengthAgainstCarriers//public
    {
        set { strengthAgainstCarriers = value; }
        get { return strengthAgainstCarriers; }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Comment: The last definition is wrong (you cannot be `public` and implement a method explicitly at the same time), but the first one should have worked.

Comment: Can you post the whole class? Or better, a minimal class wit the same problem?

Comment: Delete the generated method and try to add it again. Right-click on Iclonable and choose `Implement Interface` > `Implement Interface`. Compile to see if it works fine.

Comment: You wouldn't have defined your own class called object? If so, try defining your method like `public System.Object System.ICloneable.Clone()`

Comment: Your class compiles: http://ideone.com/aD3dc2 The error is probably elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This built fine for me.

```
public class MyClone : ICloneable
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

You don't perhaps want to share any more of your class? Nothing is really jumping out at me.